# NSDateFormater from NSMutableArray value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I store some dates in my NSMutableArray, I want to retrieve them and change the format.
For the moment I do this:

```
NSDate *myDate = [self.dates objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"myDate:%@", myDate); // 2010-03-02
NSDateFormatter *formatDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatDate setDateFormat:@"MMMM d YYYY"];

NSString *newDate = [formatDate stringFromDate:myDate];
NSLog(@"newDate: %@", newDate); // NULL
```

the result for newDate is NULL, and I want it to be something like that: "March 3, 2010"

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your dates array contains strings, you have to convert the string to an NSDate and then you can re-convert the date to the format you want.

```
NSDateFormatter *strToDateFmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[strToDateFmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *myDate = [strToDateFmt dateFromString:[self.dates objectAtIndex:0]];
[strToDateFmt release];
NSLog(@"myDate:%@", myDate);

NSDateFormatter *formatDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatDate setDateFormat:@"MMMM d YYYY"];
NSString *newDate = [formatDate stringFromDate:myDate];
[formatDate release];
NSLog(@"newDate: %@", newDate);
```

Comment: I just to it by myself just after they told me to watch the documentation, stringFromDate: was my solution. Thank you, your code is the same and its working

Answer (score 3):

That works for me, but I replaced the first line with:

```
NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date];
```

My output:

```
2010-03-02 19:29:08.045 app[11464:a0f] myDate:2010-03-02 19:29:08 -0800
2010-03-02 19:29:08.048 app[11464:a0f] newDate: March 2 2010
```

My best guess is that `[self.dates objectAtIndex:0]` isn't returning what you want it to.

Comment: thats Not what I want, its too easy if I use the [NSDate date];
I already store all my dates inside an array now I want to use them, my first line is good because I can read my date

Comment: @ludo, if your array contained a date, your code would work.  That array contains something else.  Your second line would work if it contained strings, for example.

Comment: Actually, I would guess you have a string in there, not a date - that's the most likely case.

Comment: in fact my Array contained some dates but with this format --->  2010-03-02 not like the NSDate 2010-03-02 11:38:08 +0800

Comment: @ludo: NSDates do not have a format, so that is quite odd. That's what a date formatter is for. Try logging the class of `myDate` to be sure that it is in fact an NSDate and not accidentally something else that happens to have a date-like description.

Comment: yes I have a string inside, but when I do NSDate *myDate = [self.dates objectAtIndex:0]; it didn't consider it like a date?

Comment: @ludo, my point is that it doesn't contain `NSDate` objects.  If it did, your code would work.  Try printing out `[myDate class]` to see what it really is.

Comment: @ludo: No. A string is still a string even if you make an NSDate variable point to it. Giving the variable an `NSDate*` type is just lying to compiler about what the variable points to. See my answer here for more info on how variables work in Objective-C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313836/cocoa-string-question/1313952#1313952

Comment: @ludo - `NSString` is not the same as `NSDate`.  Check out the `NSDate` documentation for how to convert back and forth.

Comment: @ludo: there is no "conversion" done when you assign a NSString to a NSDate variable.

Comment: @ludo, there are conversions, but not just by assigning a pointer of one type to a pointer of another type.  That's just crazy.

Comment: ok I understand, but its strange that there is no way for the NSDateFormater to recognize the elements of my string

Comment: @ludo, `NSDateFormatter` *can* do that.  Go check out the documentation.